# Can I request email with plain text only?

Tags: feature-request, email-notification

I'm grateful that there are both HTML and plain text sections in my daily notification emails, but every byte counts against my monthly email quotas. If I could choose to only receive plain text, I could subscribe to far more tags.

Comment: Monthly email quotas? I can recommend a few (thousands) email providers offering infinite quota, or at least one that is measured in giga-bytes.

Comment: Changing my email provider doesn't improve StackExchange.

Comment: Well, this seems like it won't have much use. And to add an option would be to clutter the UI.

Comment: Call us old fashioned, but many of us don't want HTML in our email. A single checkbox isn't that much to ask.

Comment: @bjb568 One label and one checkbox is hardly "clutter," is it?

Comment: @Doorknob "would you like us to send text? Markdown? Latex? HTML? What color would you like the text? Would you like advanced options to configure the text size? You can upload a CSS file or paste it in this textbox. Which version of CSS is this? Which parser should be used on it? Which version of HTML? Advanced options to change tag structure? Old version of email? Advanced options for what content to send? Compression? Image format?" There should be *no* options over too many.

Comment: @bjb568 By definition, plain text has NONE of that If we wanted colors, font sizes or any of your other ridiculous examples, we wouldn't want plain text.

Comment: @DavidDean They aren't related to plain text, who said they were? I'm just illustrating how choices can be useless.

Comment: @bj568 It seems odd to me to suggest that asking for a choice to get less data will result in an absurd number of other choices for more data.

Comment: As I said, having options can be harmful. I was using an irrelevant example to prove that point.

Comment: @bjb568 [for the sake of argument](http://www.xkcd.com/1432/), of course.